# Samba: creation mask 777 and create mode 666 do not work

Tags: share, samba4, permissions

Something wrong when creating file from windows.

smbd Version 4.1.6-Ubuntu

Copying the same file from same PC to same folder inside the share.

From share definition:

shares-secret.conf:    **force create mode = 0722**

shares-secret.conf:#    create mask = 0666

shares-secret.conf:#    directory mask = 0666

result:
-rwxr--r--

shares-secret.conf:#    force create mode = 0722

shares-secret.conf:    **create mask = 0666**

shares-secret.conf:#    directory mask = 0666

result:
-rwxr--r--

shares-secret.conf:#    force create mode = 0722

shares-secret.conf:#    create mask = 0666

shares-secret.conf:    **directory mask = 0666**

result:
-rwxr--r--

So, the single parameter gave no effect: group will have r/o access. Trying to use two parameters

CM=0666,DM=0666: -rwxr-xr--

CM=0666,DM=0: -rwxr-xr--

CM=0,DM=0666: -rwxr-xr--

CM=0,DM=0: -rwxr-xr--

CM=7, DM=default: -rwxr-x---

CM=70, DM=default: -rwxr-x---

FCM=666, others=default: -rw-r--r--

etc etc... So, as I can see, there's no way to enable write access for group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is simple: turn "obey pam restrictions" off. That's all!

Answer (score 1):

Humm.  I'd be interested in seeing the relevant PAM sections on that.

I had a similar problem where in spite of 'inherit permissions', create masks, and force create mode options I was unable to create files with group (or world) writable permissions.   The problem turned out to the clients, which were OSX boxes.  OSX was using a umask value of 0022.

Changing that was very difficult.

The solution turned out to be putting `umask 0002` in `/etc/launchd-user.conf`, then rebooting so launchd would re-read its startup scripts.   Apple's documentation at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201684 states that this is for 10.9 and below, but I think it only works down to version 10.4.10, at which point you have to use `defaults write -g NSUmask 2` which is good for most of 10.4 & 10.3 .    Also, the NSUmask is a convoluted base-10 representation of the usual octal code.  (warning warning)

The Terminal is it's own environment so it's umask must be set separately in `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` .

Anyway, `obey pam restrictions` had no effect for me on this issue.   The set up was FreeBSD 10.3 , samba 4.3.11 , & various OSX versions.

Comment: Sorry,  but we have no OSX boxes. Only an assortment of windoze - from aging XP to damned 10. Thus I cant set up umask on client sides